# want to create Group Template user control in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to create multiple groups of control(s) within a rectangular border. where each group will be containing control within it, surrounded by rectangular border and a header (optional) is to be placed over each child group's top-left above its border.
    So, I created a class **GroupLayout**, each child element within this have to create its own new group. I created **Header** as an attached property.

Syntax making use of template is as:-

```
<GroupLayout Orientation = "Vertical">
 <DataGrid GroupLayout.Header= "Group 1" />
 <Grid GroupLayout.Header= "Group 2" />
 -------So On--------
</GroupLayout>
```

as above given, DataGrid and Grid both should form there own two groups with vertical orientation. each child element should create its own new group.
So, I tried this as User Control:-

```
<Style TargetType = "GroupLayout">
 <Setter.Property>
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupLayout">
      <StackPanel>
        <Border x:Name="MainParentGroupBorder">
          <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter Content = "{TemplateBinding HeaderLabel}" />
            <Border x:Name="ChildGroupBorder">
              <ContentPresenter Content = "{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </StackPanel>
     </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Property>
  </Style>
```

In code behind I'm driving from ItemsControl.
But, this is not working as required. Now after a lot of efforts, I think I have to implement **ItemTemplate** in Xaml here. but I'm not able to do so to get the required result. Please help me.

Thanks,

GK Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're re-inventing the wheel.

> each group will be containing control within it, surrounded by rectangular border and a header (optional) is to be placed over each child group's top-left above its border

This is perfectly covered by an existing control: [HeaderedContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.internal.pivot.controls.headeredcontentcontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  All you have to do is provide an appropriate control template for it.  I suggest something like this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <controls:HeaderedContentControl Header="Group 1">
        <DataGrid />
    </controls:HeaderedContentControl>
    <controls:HeaderedContentControl Header="Group 2">
        <Grid />
    </controls:HeaderedContentControl>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, give the `HeaderedContentControl` the appropriate template:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:HeaderedContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:HeaderedContentControl">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border x:Name="MainParentGroupBorder">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                            <Border x:Name="ChildGroupBorder">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                   </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Edit**

Expanding on the above -- if you need the specific syntax of using an attached property `GroupLayout.Header`, then I suggest having your `GroupLayout` class override the [`ItemsControl.GetContainerForItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.  Have it return an instance of `HeaderedContentControl`:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new HeaderedContentControl();
}
```

Now, you can use another ItemsControl override -- [`PrepareContainerForItemOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) -- to pass along your attached property:

```
protected virtual void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, Object item)
{
    // get the attached property from the ItemsControl item
    string header = ((FrameworkElement)item).GetValue(GroupLayout.Header) as string;

    // set the container's "Header"
    ((HeaderedContentControl)element).Header = header;
}
```

Now you can use the exact XAML syntax you need:

```
<GroupLayout Orientation = "Vertical">
    <DataGrid GroupLayout.Header= "Group 1" />
    <Grid GroupLayout.Header= "Group 2" />
</GroupLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks McGarnagle, but can you please suggest me how can i implement the same behavior without using **HeaderContentControl**. and its not that other developer(who will be using this control) will only provide DataGrid/Grid as child element to this template control but they can  provide any child control which should create its own group.